# Android sqlite syntax error: near ")"

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I got error for creating sqlite db in android.

My code is:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user";
    public static final String COL1_USER_ID = "USER_ID";
    public static final String COL2_USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
    public static final String COL3_IMEI_CODE = "IMEI_CODE";
    public static final String COL4_REGISTRATION_ID = "REGISTRATION_ID";
    public static final String COL5_MOBILE_NUMBER = "MOBILE_NUMBER";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL1_USER_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL2_USER_NAME + TEXT_TYPE
            + COMMA_SEP + COL3_IMEI_CODE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL4_REGISTRATION_ID + VARCHAR_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL5_MOBILE_NUMBER + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + ")";
```

Error message is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE user(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,USER_ID TEXT,USER_NAME TEXT,IMEI_CODE TEXT,REGISTRATION_ID VARCHAR(255),MOBILE_NUMBER TEXT,)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Why there is comma at the end of your query ?

Comment: What exactly was unclear with this error message? It is relatively clear that the problem is here `...MOBILE_NUMBER TEXT,)` and it is clear, that the comma is misplaced.

Answer (score 7):

You should remove `+ COMMA_SEP`  at last

### Corrected

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL1_USER_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL2_USER_NAME + TEXT_TYPE
    + COMMA_SEP + COL3_IMEI_CODE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL4_REGISTRATION_ID + VARCHAR_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL5_MOBILE_NUMBER + TEXT_TYPE + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below lines of code instead of yours.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL1_USER_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL2_USER_NAME + TEXT_TYPE
            + COMMA_SEP + COL3_IMEI_CODE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL4_REGISTRATION_ID + VARCHAR_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL5_MOBILE_NUMBER + TEXT_TYPE + ")";
```

There is one more comma at last, actually there is no need of it.